# Summarizing the array + counting the instances

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sorting

I have an array with the phone and a timestamp, which I've rounded to the nearest quarter.

The array input is attached the end of my comments.

What I'm trying to do is rather complex and I've tried to use a combination of map/filter/reduce functions but am not sure in what order I should approach it.

What I would like is the following, with a count of each phone by the time, sorted by top phones of the day - in addition it must display 0 for hours that are not present.

**The ideal output:**

```
[{
  "OPPO R11s": [{
    "time": 00:00,
    "count": 20
  }, {
    "time": 00:15,
    "count": 13
  }, {
    "time": 00:30,
    "count": 0
  }, {
    "time": 00:45,
    "count": 23
  }], 
  "iPhone 7": [{
        "time": 00:00,
        "count": 20
      }]
}]
```

**The input:**

```
[
  {
    "phone": "OPPO R11s",
    "roundedTime": "10:45"
  },
  {
    "phone": "iPhone 7",
    "roundedTime": "03:15"
  },
  {
    "phone": "Samsung Galaxy XCover 4",
    "roundedTime": "11:45"
  },
  {
    "phone": "iPhone XS Max",
    "roundedTime": "12:00"
  },
  {
    "phone": "iPhone XS",
    "roundedTime": "01:00"
  },
  {
    "phone": "Samsung Galaxy Note9",
    "roundedTime": "02:30"
  },
  {
    "phone": "Samsung Galaxy J4",
    "roundedTime": "07:15"
  },
  {
    "phone": "iPhone XS Max",
    "roundedTime": "03:00"
  },
  {
    "phone": "Samsung Galaxy J4 Plus",
    "roundedTime": "02:45"
  },
  {
    "phone": "iPhone 6s",
    "roundedTime": "12:45"
  },
  {
    "phone": "iPhone XS Max AirPods Bundle",
    "roundedTime": "01:00"
  }]
```

To explain further:

- I would like the phone to be ranked by the total number of occurrences in the array (i.e. if iPhone has occurred the most, it would be at the top of the output array).
- The time is in 15 minute intervals so it would just be going through the array and counting how many "iPhone 6s" we had during 00:15 for example.

Comment: I'm not clear on what you mean by "top phones of the day". What is your metric? Where are `count` and the quarter times coming from?

Comment: Updated in comments @ggorlen

Comment: Sorry, I'm still lost. `"OPPO R11s"` and `"IPhone 7"` are in the result array, but they only have 1 occurrence each in the input array with an array of data that was nonexistent in the input array. Everything else in the input array was discarded--why?

Comment: Sorry, but the input array is only a sub set and it's possible for Oppo R11s to occur more than once in 10:45

Comment: OK, I assumed as much, but why not post a complete I/O so we can follow your logic? You haven't explained why most of the input was discarded in the output. "It's not possible for Oppo R11s to occur more than once in 10:45". Please elaborate, I don't feel like this is common knowledge. I'm unclear what you're asking here.

Comment: Maybe add your code which you tried as well

Answer (score 0):

OK - I think what you want is this:

Array of objects that contain the phone name with a list of all times that phone was used.  Array should be sorted.

First go through input, add entries into map with a counter.  For each time that phone comes up, search its time list.  If the time exists, increment it, if not add the time.  Then map phone list to array with objects that wrap the phone data to the phone name.  Move counts and sort

```js
const phoneMap = {};

const log = [
  {
"phone": "OPPO R11s",
"roundedTime": "10:45"
  },
  {
"phone": "iPhone 7",
"roundedTime": "03:15"
  },
  {
"phone": "Samsung Galaxy XCover 4",
"roundedTime": "11:45"
  },
  {
"phone": "iPhone XS Max",
"roundedTime": "12:00"
  },
  {
"phone": "iPhone XS",
"roundedTime": "01:00"
  },
  {
"phone": "Samsung Galaxy Note9",
"roundedTime": "02:30"
  },
  {
"phone": "Samsung Galaxy J4",
"roundedTime": "07:15"
  },
  {
"phone": "iPhone XS Max",
"roundedTime": "03:00"
  },
  {
"phone": "Samsung Galaxy J4 Plus",
"roundedTime": "02:45"
  },
  {
"phone": "iPhone 6s",
"roundedTime": "12:45"
  },
  {
"phone": "iPhone XS Max AirPods Bundle",
"roundedTime": "01:00"
  }];

log.forEach(function(logItem) {
  if (!phoneMap[logItem["phone"]]) {
    phoneMap[logItem["phone"]] = {count:1, times:[]};
  } else {
   phoneMap[logItem["phone"]]["count"]++
  }

  var timeNode = phoneMap[logItem["phone"]]["times"].find(function(timeNode) {
    return timeNode["time"] === logItem["roundedTime"];
  })

  if (timeNode) {
    timeNode["count"]++;
  } else {
    phoneMap[logItem["phone"]]["times"].push({
      "time": logItem["roundedTime"],
      "count":1
    });
  }
})

var result = Object.keys(phoneMap).map(function(key){
 let obj = {};
  obj[key] = phoneMap[key];
  obj["count"] = phoneMap[key].count;
  delete phoneMap[key]["count"];
 return obj;
}).sort(function(a,b){
 return b.count - a.count;
});


console.log(result);
```